# How to make label.text equal to a custom object's value in an array?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Currently I have some custom JSON objects:

```
class JSONObjects {

  var airbnbUS: String
  var airbnbLocal: String
  var image: URL


  init(airbnbUS: String, airbnbLocal: String, image: URL){

    self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
    self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
    self.image = image
  }
```

After parsing the json I then transfer an array of the custom object through a segue to be presented on a detail view controller:

```
 var jsonObjectsArray: [JSONObjects] = []

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "practiceTableToDetailSegue" {

      if let detailVC = segue.destination as? PracticeDetailViewController {
        self.jsonObjectsArray = detailVC.jsonObjectArray
      }
    }
  }
```

On the detail view controller I would like to take elements of the custom object array and show them via a label but when I try to access the array the only options I get are

> .count, .capacity, etc.

I'm trying to present the custom object values in the labels and imageView but its not giving me the option to access the custom object values:

```
 class PracticeDetailViewController: UIViewController {

  var jsonObjectArray: [JSONObjects] = []


  @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var bottomLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.topLabel.text = jsonObjectArray.airbnbUS  //DOES NOT WORK!
    self.bottomLabel.text = jsonObjectArray.airbnbLocal //DOES NOT WORK!
    self.image.image = UIImage(data: jsonObjectArray.image) //DOES NOT WORK!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access the properties of your `JSONObjects` on the array rather than the elements of the array.

Try this:

```
self.topLabel.text = jsonObjectArray[0].airbnbUS  //DOES WORK!
self.bottomLabel.text = jsonObjectArray[0].airbnbLocal //DOES WORK!
self.image.image = UIImage(data: jsonObjectArray[0].image) //DOES WORK!
```

Also, a style comment: I'd recommend making your classes singular (i.e. `JSONObject` rather than `JSONObjects`). When you instantiate an object you're only making one object, not a bunch of `JSONObjects`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
class PracticeDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var jsonObjectArray: [JSONObjects] = []


    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.jsonObjectArray.append(JSONObjects(airbnbUS: "airbnbUS", airbnbLocal: "airbnbLocal", image: URL(string: "url")!))


        self.topLabel.text = jsonObjectArray[0].airbnbUS
        self.bottomLabel.text = jsonObjectArray[0].airbnbLocal

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: jsonObjectArray[0].image)
            self.image.image = UIImage(data: data)
        } catch {}

    }
}
```